# How to get right value for the first field of crypttab?

Tags: cryptsetup

I've lost my crypttab and I can't find a way to restore it. On another automatic installation it's 'sda5_crypt', but I can't find a command to list it.

Comment: There's no catch-all way to restore `/etc/crypttab` unless you have a copy of it. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I actually already posted the answer, but I did write both the question and the answer in a state of exhaustion so they are far from perfect. And the answer was not even recognized as one by some moderator and deleted. I'll try to undelete it. The target name is listed in the error that `update-initramfs` throws. It just doesn't look like one.

Comment: Nope, I can't undelete it. Um. @Mitch, it was the answer, can you please undelete it so I can edit it and make it better?

Comment: Or just delete this whole question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's listed in the warning that is displayed when updating initramfs with `update-initramfs`.

It can be something like `luks-a9a75bdb-fa57-454a-88c6-9f2c8d324bd0` or `sda5_crypt`.

Comment: It is the answer that solved my problem. It wasn't obvious at first because I was tired at the time of writing.